# NSUserDefaults, do something on first load only

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to do show an alert the first time the app is launched.  I'd also like to show this alert if they go into a settings page later on and want to see it again.  I figured I could set a boolean in the `NSUserDefaults`.  I'm not quite sure how to do that though (assuming this approach is right).  I thought in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:options`, I could get the value for key `@"FirstTimeLaunched"`, and in `applicationWillTerminate`, I could set the object for that key to `NO`.  If this is the case, how do I get the `BOOL` to be `YES` for the first time?

Also, do I need to set it to `NO` in `didEnterBackground` mode as well?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just think it backwards, instead of expecting a `YES`, set a variable when the app is actually launched, and remove it when the user says so in the settings.

At launch:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasBeenLaunched"]) {
    // show your only-one-time view
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasBeenLaunched"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

And when the user wants to see it again, just remove the key:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"hasBeenLaunched"];
```

When accessing a key that does not exists, `NSUserDefaults` will return `nil`.

Comment: Thank you.. I want to show specific controller once at first time app install on Device after ,How could I achieve this? ,Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Note that `synchronize` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First time App is launched, so I don't think you will ever need to set that `BOOL` to `NO`. `UserDefaults` gets deleted if App is removed. and we set it when App is first launched application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstTimeLaunched"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

If you set `Bool` to `NO` in `applicationWillTerminate`, then everytime user kills app from tray you will show alert on app launched. Again it depends on your business requirements.

Comment: How does that work?  if (myBool) { //show alert; } then in the applicationDidFinishLaunching, it will show the alert the first time.  Won't it show it again the next time the app is launched since that value is still YES?

Comment: if(myBool) // dont show alert. Assuming you are setting bool to YES when app launches frst time. else show alert.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the opposite approach and first launch check for a key called appHasLaunchedPreviously.

If it's yes then bypass the alert. 
If it's not YES then show the alert and immediately set it ready for next time.