# Change the view controller app launches with when button is clicked - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, launch

I'm attempting to create an introduction to my iOS app.  So I've created a few view controllers that are shown in the beginning of the app.  On the last introduction view controller there is a button which brings you to "the actual app".

How do I make it so when that button is clicked the app launches with a different view controller.

If someone could walk me through the steps and be very detailed I would appreciate it as I'm a beginner iOS developer.

Comment: Do you mean with different navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store whether "view intro" is set to true/false & set this value in NSUserDefaults. Check that value when the app starts & put an if/else to load the appropriate VC. You might want to make the button "skip" intro entirely & set this value. People generally get annoyed w/long intros & want to use your app. See [this answer about NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983411/nsuserdefaults-do-something-on-first-load-only).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are creating an "app tutorial" type of introduction. Also assuming that you only want this to occur the first time the user uses the app, then go directly to the app every other time.

I would store a didWatchTutorial BOOL value in the NSUserDefaults.

This would also need to include an if/else statement in the opening view controller of your app, which controls (based on this BOOL value) if the user should be shown the tutorial:

```
if (didWatchTutorial) {
    //GO STRAIGHT TO APP
} else {
    //SHOW TUTORIAL
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  What should the if/else statement be?

Comment: It depends how you have your app setup. To be honest, I would make the view controllers you have mentioned into UIViews. Then the if else statment would be: if (!didWatchTutorial) { //initialize and show UIViews...}